# .htaccess redirect if file exist then redirect back

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I'm trying to do if user navigate to url/dir/test.ext ( each time )

- check if /dir/test.ext exist
- if exist redirect it to url/index.php
- then from index.php redirect it back to /var/test.ext

What I've tried so far:

.htacess:
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

index.php: catch the redirect to url,check if not visited before, setcookie that expire after 1s that the user came from $1 page, redirect back - I'm sure there's an error with this mechanism -

The problem with .htaccess is that it'll work only if the file doesn't exist ( !-f rule ), if I change it to (-f) I'll get `Internal Server Error` as it'll enter infinite redirection loop.

Comment: What is the full goal of this? I think you are trying to redirect users from a place that does not exist like /dir/doesnotexist.ext to your index, but the second redirect does not make sense. Why would you redirect them again once they get to index.php? I would use 404 pages for this. You can set a special 404 error page with a redirect in it. You could also set a session variable that your index checks for and if found forwards them, but they will not be able to visit your index until that session is destroyed again. Can you give more info?

Comment: @TylerRadlick I'm not trying to redirect if file dosn't exist. I'm trying to redirect to index.php only if the file exist. user visit url/a.php?b=c -> check if a.php exist -> redirect to index.php -> redirect back to a.php?b=c. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

404 Page Code:

```
<?php $_SESSION['notallowed'] = 'notallowed';
header("location:http://dir/index.php");
?>
```

This code runs when the user hits a directory or file that does not exist, sets a session and redirects them to index.

index.php code

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['notallowed']){ header("location:http://dir/var/test.ext");?>
```

This code checks for the session and if found redirects to /var/test.ext